# Swift: download and open pdf file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pdf, download

Excuse me if it's a stupid question but I didn't find an answer: what's the default pdf reader in iPhone? Is it iBooks for all iPhones? I ask about this because in my swift application I want to download a pdf file then open it by the default pdf reader (or another application) of the device. Still now I can do that with to ways: the first is when the button "Download" is tapped, I let the user choose the way of downloading the file via `UIDocumentInteractionController` then he can import it using iBooks, Documents, Chrome... I tested it and it works perfectly. The second way is to download the file inside the application (I got the example from the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479812/saving-pdf-files-with-swift-in-ios-and-display-them)) then open it by a pdf reader (the default native one if this is possible).

Any suggestions please?

Comment: How we can do it by UIDocumentInteractionController ? Any Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the PDF is available on the web, would it be enough to open it in the browser? This would be a trivially simple method:

```
if let url = URL(string: "http://path.to/your.pdf") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Safari also offers the option to open the file in another app, if the user wants to use something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to open it in the browser and also in an UIWebView. Sorry and thanks again :)

Comment: how can i open if pdf is in documents of an iphone

Comment: @XcodianSolangi Check this >>  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682393/2226263

Comment: This dont allow open pdf links