# Unable to open downloaded pdf path in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, alamofire

i am trying to implement pdf download option once user tap on download option pdf file should be downloaded and get open. I tried following link but its not working
 [Saving PDF Files with Swift in iOS and display them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479812/saving-pdf-files-with-swift-in-ios-and-display-them) and I tried following code. In response its showing Path I gone through with that path but I didn't find any file.

```
 @objc func downloadPdfFile(_ sender : UIButton)
    {
        var localDic :NSDictionary!
        localDic = totalSyllabusArray.object(at: sender.tag) as! NSDictionary
        let filepath = localDic["filepath"] as! String
        let pdfURLString:String = FETCH_InMegh_Image_BaseURL + filepath
        let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
        let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("downloadedFile.pdf")
        //Create URL to the source file you want to download
        let fileURL = URL(string: pdfURLString)
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success
                if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for open the PDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @kishore Apple recently added PDfKit Framework try this below link.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit

Here what all you need to do is Take One UIView in storyboard to display Pdf files . and in Identity Inspector set class as PDFView.
 Take outlet like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var pdfVw: PDFView!
```

And use following code.

```
 let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "Pass your Pdf Path here")
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
                pdfVw.autoScales = true
                pdfVw.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfVw.displayDirection = .vertical
                pdfVw.document = pdfDocument
```

Comment: Happieee coding (: