# How to download a PDF document when comes in Data type from WS, i dont have any URL the pdf comes from web service swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i got show the pdf with next lines

```
webView.load(decodeData, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
```

however i cant find the way to download it, how can i download it using a button the next lines are a little part

```
if let form = eDocument{
            self.title = "Follow"
            if let decodeData = Data(base64Encoded: form.content, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
               let str = String(decoding: decodeData, as: UTF8.self)
                webView.load(decodeData, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
            }
        }
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving PDF Files with Swift in iOS and display them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479812/saving-pdf-files-with-swift-in-ios-and-display-them)

Comment: @Nathan the problem is, i dont have any URL, the info comes from WS